# Having issue appending JSON data to Html tables

Tags: java, json, ajax, html

This function gets the IP address and I want to store each address in a separate box like 192.168.10.1 each address "192""168" should be in a different table data box. Which I have three tables to store IP Address, Network mask, Gateway.

```
function ipcfg_get () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
            url: '/ipcfg/ipcfg_get.cgi',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var a= + data.ipv4.addr;
                var m= + data.ipv4.mask;
                var g= + data.ipv4.gw;

            var rows = $('tr', $('#ip1','#ip2','#ip3','#ip4').append);
            var rows = $('tr', $('#nm1','#nm2','#nm3','#nm4').append);
            var rows = $('tr', $('#gw1','#gw2','#gw3','#gw4').append);

              if (data.hasOwnProperty('attr')) {
                       var lst = data.attr;
                       for (i = 0; i < lst.length; ++i) {
                          var tr = rows.eq(i);
                          var val = lst[i];

    var html =  '<td>' + a + '</td>' + 
                '<td>' + m + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + g + '</td>' ;

                tr.html(html);
                       }
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status) { }    
            });
```

Table format for storing the IP Address.

```
<section>
            <table class="formgrid">
                <tr><th>IP Address:</th><td><input type="text" name="a1" id="ip1" size="3" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="a2" size="3" id="ip2" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="a3" size="3" id="ip3" value="0">.
                <input type="text" name="a4" size="3" id="ip4" value="0"></td></tr>
```

Comment: what's the problem ? what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I need to get IPv4 information which is gotten through the function and on clicking the reset button I want to get the set IP address displayed .

Comment: why do you have 3 lines starting like `var rows =`? What did you want to do with the `.append` at the end of those lines?

Comment: To append the values of each text box of the IP address with the one from the function call